# Override nuspec variable from TeamCity

Tags: command-line, nuget, teamcity, pipeline, nuspec

I've already overridden the version number in the `nuspec` through the build steps in TeamCity (Nuget Pack), but I don't know how to override any specific variable - is it only possible with the `Command Line Parameters` or is it possible to expand it in some way so that a new parameter is possible in the build step (as is with the `version` parameter)?

If only through the command line, do any have suggestions? I guess a path is needed as with the `Package Parameter`, but other than that I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Properties` field is what you're looking for:

[image]

According to the docs, it can contain:

> Semicolon or new-line separated list of **package creation properties**.
>   For example, to make a release build, you define here
>   Configuration=Release.

I've highlighted the term `package creation properties` as this is the out-of-the-box mechanism to pass parameters to the NuGet package creation process.

Comment: Thanks Yan, I've seen that, but I want to override the parameter in my .nuspec that contains the 'git-commit-id' from teamfoundation - can that be done via the package creation properties? If so - how, If I may ask?

Comment: maybe AssemblyInformationVersion is a way around, but again, I'm not sure and therefore hoped someone in here had tried it (most probably).

Comment: > can that be done via the package creation properties?
I would expect that to be possible, but haven't tried exactly this scenario myself.

Comment: Hmm.. Trying to add extra parameter like: "Configuration=Release; Author=SomethingSomething", but nothing changes? I wish to add the commit id to the nuspec, so now I try to simplify it by just changing the <author> to something, but that doesn't change either..